# How do I create a random hue overlay in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, random, colors, hue

I'm currently working on a random image generator, which combines different .png files (attributes) into one image. I have managed to get these working, however there's one part I want for my project that I haven't been able to find out how to do.

I realise there are ways to do this in CSS and HTML, however neither of these suffice for what I need. The character is generated in the JavaScript portion of my code, and thus for it to work I need JavaScript.

Here's an example of a piece of code in JavaScript that generates one of the body parts. In this case, it's the body.

```
        //body
    var characterbody = new Image();
    var characterbodynum=Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+1; 
    var characterbodyname="body" + characterbodynum + ".png";
    characterbody.src=characterbodyname;
```

To explain this code: The first line indicates an image. The second line indicates to the computer that there are four images, and one should be randomly selected.
The third line indicates based on files saved to my computer it needs to find a file named "body", followed by a number, and then .png on the end. For example, if the random whole number between 1 and 4 chooses the number 3, it picks body3.png and places that .png file into the overall image.

What I want now is an overlay to be added which will randomly select a hue value and shift the hue of the picture that amount. Preferably, I'd like it to work like the code above somewhat so it will be easy to implement into my code.

I'm guessing, but I could be wrong, is the `style.filter` the right code to use to do this?

Comment: Yes, `style.filter` is the way to go, you can do something like `characterbody .style.filter = 'hue-rotate(' + Math.floor(Math.random()*360) + 'deg)';` [more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/hue-rotate)

Comment: I tried putting that line of code in, it ended up not working. I'm guessing there's something missing, but am unsure what. I tried

`//hue overlay
characterthue .style.filter = 'hue-rotate(' + Math.floor(Math.random()*360) + 'deg)';`

and it didn't work. At least on its own it doesn't work. Any ideas why, and how to get it working?

Comment: Oh, my bad, there is an extra space in there, it should be `characterbody.style.filter...` instead of `characterbody .style.filter...`. There should be no space between `characterbody` and `.style`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. What I forgot to do was declare a new variable, but I'm not sure what to classify the variable as. `characterbody` is a variable, so I'd imagine there needs to be a line above the line you gave me that says `var characterbody = ` and then the type of variable it is. However, I'm not sure which kind of variable it is supposed to be.

Comment: I thought there already was a `characterbody` variable, in the code that you have in your question there is `var characterbody = new Image();`. That means that if you add the `characterbody.style.filter = 'hue-rotate(' + Math.floor(Math.random()*360) + 'deg)';` statement at the end of the code in your question, this will work.

Comment: I think something's still not clicking. So from beginning to end, this piece of code reads: 

`var characterbody= new Image();
characterbody.style.filter = 'hue-rotate(' + Math.floor(Math.random()*360) + 'deg)';`

It doesn't work. It doesn't break the code, but this block of code doesn't do anything.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing differently but here is a code snippet that shows that my suggestion works: https://jsbin.com/zebotuwuva/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Point proven, your code works, that's awesome. However, there's one issue, as I need to apply this to an image that's being created by the programme and not a pre-existing image. So where it says `characterbodyname` you give a URL that links to a picture of a basket. How can I implement this into my own code?

Comment: The value of `characterbodyname` doesn't make any difference as long as it is a valid URL to an image file (be it `bodyN.png` or the URL that I've used). The important part is `characterbody` which is an `<img>` element. If that is the case in your code as it is in mine, you can style that element (add a `CSS` `filter` property to it).

Comment: Okay, how do I do that? Here's my code:

`var characterbody = new Image();
        var characterbodyname = "file:///C:/Users/Me/Pictures/CharacterCreator/AvatarMaker.html"";
        characterbody.src = characterbodyname;
        characterbody.style.filter = "hue-rotate(" + Math.floor (Math.random()*360) + "deg)";`

Comment: You have this `..../AvatarMaker.html""`, there is an extra quote (`"`) at the end there and the file's extension is `.html`. Is that file an actual image and is that extra quote only here on in the code that you're using as well ?

Comment: That was a typo when I copied the code over. That extra quote isn't in my actual code.

`var characterbody = new Image();         var characterbodyname = "file:///C:/Users/Me/Pictures/CharacterCreator/AvatarMaker.html";         characterbody.src = characterbodyname;         characterbody.style.filter = "hue-rotate(" + Math.floor (Math.random()*360) + "deg)";`

I don't think this method is working. How do I do the CSS filter thing?